# WIX: Using a condition to stop uninstall?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm writing an installer file in WiX with a custom action defined in a DLL. The custom action runs on uninstall, and if it fails, I want it to stop the uninstall process and rollback. The action doesn't affect the system, so I am able to call it before `InstallInitialize`, so it shouldn't have other changes to undo.

I was told that if I defined a property for the custom action, I could then use `condition` to halt the uninstallation process, as follows:

```
<SetProperty Id="CA_mine" 
             Value="No" Sequence="execute" 
             Before="CA_mine">
  Installed AND remove=ALL
</SetProperty> 
<CustomAction Id="CA_mine" BinaryKey="BIN_mine" DllEntry="mine" Execute="immediate"/>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="CA_mine"
          Before="InstallInitialize">
    Installed AND remove=ALL      
  </Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>

<Condition>
  NOT (Installed AND remove=ALL)  OR [CA_mine] = "No"
</Condition>
```

Where `mine` sets the property `CA_mine` to be "Yes" if I want the uninstall to stop.

Would this even work? When is the `condition` tag evaluated? Is there a simpler way to accomplish my goal here (rolling back uninstallation when `mine` fails)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Condition element, when nested under the Product element, refers to the LaunchConditions table.

Your custom action needs to be scheduled before the [LaunchConditions action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) so that the property is set and available for evaluation.  Think of it as an extension to the [AppSearch action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367578%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).